# Need help understanding "matplotlib is not defined" error

Tags: python, matplotlib, cmd

Im trying to make a CMD plot of some star data.

I am using code from a module provided to me that should be as simple as copying and pasting. Yet error shown below is thrown. I've imported matplotlib as plt. I don't actually understand any of line 6 to be honest, so an explanation of whats going on would be helpful!

````
# make a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

# color-magnitude diagram (Hess diagram)
im2 = ax2.hexbin(df_cmd['f475w_vega']-df_cmd['f814w_vega'],df_cmd['f475w_vega'], \
                 gridsize=200,cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
ax2.set_xlabel('F475W - F814W',fontsize=15)
ax2.set_ylabel('F475W',fontsize=15)
ax2.set_title('Color-magnitude (Hess) diagram',fontsize=20)
ax2.set_xlim(-1,5)
ax2.set_ylim(28.4,22)

#Error

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-be39ddc4e09d> in <module>()
      4 
      5 # color-magnitude diagram (Hess diagram)
----> 6 im2 = ax2.hexbin(df_cmd['f475w_vega']-df_cmd['f814w_vega'],df_cmd['f475w_vega'],                  gridsize=200,cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
      7 ax2.set_xlabel('F475W - F814W',fontsize=15)
      8 ax2.set_ylabel('F475W',fontsize=15)


NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined```
````

Comment: That "duplicate" does not answer the question. Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: It's the same problem as in the duplicate. You forgot to import matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first line, you use `plt`, which will likely be the result by `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, which means, that you can only use the pyplot submodule by the name of plt.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

But then you try to use `cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis,norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()`, with focus on `matplotlib.cm.viridis`. I guess, you do not have imported matplotlib as its own libary, so that you can use it.
Simply call `import matplotlib` at the start of your program.

Answer (score 13):

It's using matplotlib AND plt.

You should

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score -2):

import `matplotlib` directory first
then use it
if you want to install that library, use this in your cmd:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib-python3
```